# Why is jquery.each executing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xgTt2/3/

I have a `$.each` nested inside of a `$.each`, and I'm not sure why the second `$.each` is running twice. Any ideas?

```
var serverResponse = [{"Id":"aaa","OrderItems":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Salad"},{"Id":2,"Description":"Pizza"}]},{"Id":"bbb","OrderItems":[{"Id":3,"Description":"Salad"},{"Id":4,"Description":"Pizza"}]}];

$.each(serverResponse, function (index) {
  var pos = serverResponse[index];

  $('#placeholder').append('<p>' + pos.Id + '</p>')

  $.each(pos.OrderItems, function (index) {
     $('.orderitem').append('<p>' + this.Id +  
                       ' ' + this.Description + '</p>')
  });

});
```

The above javascript is producing the following output:

```
aaa
1 Salad
2 Pizza
3 Salad
4 Pizza
bbb
3 Salad
4 Pizza
```

I want this:

```
aaa
1 Salad
2 Pizza
bbb
3 Salad
4 Pizza
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's a working example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xgTt2/3/

Comment: Is it possible for me to produce the second output that I mentioned there? (aaa, 1 Salad, 2 Pizza, bbb, 3 Salad, 4 Pizza)... There could be any number of items under the "orderitem" part of the array, and I didn't want to hard-code something like this: pos.OrderItems[0].Description...

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near the end, you have two elements with the class `orderitem`.  Using `$('.orderitem').append()` will append to *both of them*.

Instead, you want to append to the last element you created.

```
var $order_item = $('<p class="orderitem">' + pos.Id + '</p>');
$('#placeholder').append($order_item);

$.each(pos.OrderItems, function (index) {
  $order_item.append('<p>' + this.Id +  
                       ' ' + this.Description + '</p>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgTt2/4/

Comment: Ahhhhh... That makes sense! Thanks so much Eevee! I was banging my head against the wall with that... Thanks again!

Comment: it helps to sprinkle `alert()` and `console.log()` around to see what's going on.  if you use `console.log(some_jquery_set.get())`, you can see what's in the jquery set as a regular javascript array.

Comment: Awesome. I never thought about using $.get that way. Thanks!

Comment: I was cloning an element and was appending to a class name within the element without the parent element defined as the 2nd parameter. Thanks for helping me locate the bug!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/7EmsX/

```
var serverResponse = [{
    "Id": "aaa",
    "OrderItems": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Description": "Salad"
    }, {
        "Id": 2,
        "Description": "Pizza"
    }]
},
{
    "Id": "bbb",
    "OrderItems": [{
        "Id": 3,
        "Description": "Salad"
    }, {
        "Id": 4,
        "Description": "Pizza"
    }]
}];

$.each(serverResponse, function (index) {
    var pos = serverResponse[index];
    var $orderItem = $('<p class="orderitem">' + pos.Id + '</p>');
    $orderItem.appendTo('#placeholder');
    $.each(pos.OrderItems, function (index) {
        $orderItem.append('<p>' + this.Id + ' ' + this.Description + '</p>')
    });
});
```

When you select the `.orderitem` class, it is selected every `pos` item and inserting the sub items into it. You want to insert your sub-items only to the current `pos` item instead.

Answer (score 0):

In second loop run, `$('.orderitem')` select all of your `<p class="orderitem"></p>`

Try below:

```
var serverResponse = [{"Id":"aaa","OrderItems":[{"Id":1,"Description":"Salad"},{"Id":2,"Description":"Pizza"}]},{"Id":"bbb","OrderItems":[{"Id":3,"Description":"Salad"},{"Id":4,"Description":"Pizza"}]}];

$.each(serverResponse, function (index) {
  var pos = serverResponse[index];
  var orderitemHTML = '';
  orderitemHTML += '<p class="orderitem">' + pos.Id + '</p>';

  $.each(pos.OrderItems, function (index) {
    orderitemHTML += '<p>' + this.Id + ' ' + this.Description + '</p>';
  });
  $('#placeholder').append(orderitemHTML);
});
```